# Forward request by springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Due to the strict cookie policy of Safari browser, I can't call the example2.com URLs on the example1.com domain page.

Now I want to solve this problem by forwarding the backend, that is, all the requests on the page are sent to example1.com. If the interface the page wants to call is `example2.com/user/mine`, the page can be `example1.com/example2-api/user/mine`, the backend forwards it to `example2.com/user/mine`, and returns the return value obtained from the `example2.com/user/mine` to the front end.

All the parameters carried by the page when requesting `http://example1.com/example2-api/user/mine` need to be transferred to `http://example2.com/user/mine` as they are, such as the parameters on the body or url, or the request header.

Do you have any ideas to implement this function through the interceptor? Thank you very much for your help!

I have tried to regenerate an HTTP request using the information received by the request and send it using RestTemplate, but the response is garbled.

```java
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Component
public class ForwardInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public ForwardInterceptor(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        // 获取原始请求的URL、请求方法、请求体和请求头
        String originalUrl = request.getRequestURI();
        String originalMethod = request.getMethod();
        String originalBody = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        HttpHeaders originalHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
            String headerValue = request.getHeader(headerName);
            originalHeaders.add(headerName, headerValue);
        }

        // 构建转发请求的URL
        String forwardUrl = "http://example2.com" + originalUrl;

        // 创建转发请求
        RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(originalBody, originalHeaders, HttpMethod.valueOf(originalMethod), URI.create(forwardUrl));

        // 发送转发请求
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);

        // 将转发请求的响应设置到原始响应中
        response.setStatus(responseEntity.getStatusCodeValue());
        response.setContentType(responseEntity.getHeaders().getContentType().toString());
        response.getWriter().write(responseEntity.getBody());

        return false; // 停止后续处理
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        // 在请求处理完成后的操作
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        // 在请求完成后的操作
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because when the client sends a request, it brings Accept-Encoding, telling the server that it can be returned with GZIP compression, but the RestTemplate does not support GZIP by default, so when the return data is converted into string, even letters and numbers.

Solutions:

1. Remove the Accept-Entiding manually, and directly remove the request head in the code

   originalHeaders.remove(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING);
2. Configure RestTemplate, support GZIP

- this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClientBuilder.create().build()));
- add httpclient dependency

  org.apache.httpcomponents
      httpclient